# Ubuntu 22.04 don't print to my network canon TR4720 printer

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, canon

I've tried every option to add the printer from settings. My printer canon TR4720 has several options under TR4700. Some don't load in to the printer setting, some do. The ones that I can add to my printer in settings don't work.  They worked on Ubuntu 18.04, I did an distro upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 and then to 22.04. It didn't work on on 20.04 or 22.04. I've been threw most of the suggestions that google search turned up. Either the repositories don't exist or the files in them. I even tried editing the cups config file /etc/cups/cups.conf To allow network etc. At a loss, Gary

Answer (score 0):

Access the CUPS (Common Unix Printing Sysyem) GUI by pointing your browser  to `http://localhost:631`.

You can detect, add, and manage printers from the `Admin` tab, and deal with individual printers from the `Printers` tab. You can set the system default printer.

From the command line,

```
lpstat -t
```

will show the total state of the printing system.

Comment: thx, I'll give that a try.